# Save files into specified directory in Qt

Tags: qt, savefiledialog

I'm trying to save a stringlist of files into a specified directory. All I found was saveFileDialog where I save only one file at a time. Is there any other way to save multiple files into the target folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QFileDialog` ist for a user to choose a location for saving, not the actual saving process. How you save a list of files depends on what exactly you have, if you mean a `QStringList` of file locations you simply want to copy the easiest way would be something like this:

```
QStringList input_file_locations;
QString output_file_location = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(...);
for (int i = 0; i < input_file_locations.size(); i++)
{
    QFile::copy(input_file_locations.at(i), output_file_location + QString::number(i));
}
```

(I did non add the extraction and preservation of the actual file name to keep the example as simple as possible)

Comment: It's a client server application where I need to save files, that the server sent over to client.I want to save a Qstringlist of files, without specifying any input file location.

Comment: `A QStringList of files` makes no sense. A `QStringList` is a list of strings. Not of files. What do the strings contain? If not file locations then the content you want to write to files?